# CakePHP 4 Mail with PDF attachment

Tags: php, email, pdf, cakephp-4.x

I am trying to attach a PDF file to the CakePHP Mailer function by using the export function that I made. However not any of the solutions I came up with seem to work. Please have a look at my code.

```
public function exportOrder($orderId = null) {      
    if ($orderId != null) {
        $order = $this->Orders->findById($orderId)->contain(['Suppliers'])->first();
        $order->products = unserialize($order->products);

        $data = [];
        $data['order'] = $order;
        $data['route'] = 'coreSections/orderCoreSection/pdf/order';

        $this->set(compact('data'));

        /* Render PDF */
        $this->viewBuilder()->setClassName('CakePdf.Pdf');

        $this->viewBuilder()->setOption(
            'pdfConfig',
            [
                'filename' => $data['order']['receipt_name'] . '.pdf',
                'download' => false
            ]
        );

        return $this->render('/Element/coreSections/orderCoreSection/pdf/order');
    }
}
```

First I create a instance of a PDF, which works for a direct export, by calling on the above function and store it. Secondly I try the send the mail with the rendered pdf as attachemnt, this gives me the error saying: *File must be a filepath or UploadedFileInterface instance. Found object instead*. The format the PDF is stored in is 'application/pdf'as indicated by a debug. This error, which is created by the mail function, is shown below:

```
$pdf = $this->exportOrder(6);

    debug($pdf);

    $email = new Mailer();
    $email->setTransport('mail');
    $email->setFrom(['mail@mail.com' => 'website.com'])
        ->setTo('mail@mail.com')
        ->setSubject('Test')
        ->setAttachments([
            'test.pdf' =>[
                'file' => $pdf,
                'mimetype' => 'MIME-Version: 1.0'
            ]
        ])
        ->deliver('Test');
```

What I would like to know if is possible to send a mail with the current object or how I could possibly save it as a file so I can use that instead as an attachment?

Other suggestions are also welcome!

Thanks in advace

Comment: What does that `debug($pdf)` line show you?

Comment: Hi, it gives me the following output:

`object(Cake\Http\Response) id:0 {
'status' => (int) 200
'contentType' => 'application/pdf'
'headers' => [ ]
'file' => null
'fileRange' => [ ]
'cookies' => object(Cake\Http\Cookie\CookieCollection) id:1 { }
'cacheDirectives' => [ ]
'body' => '%PDF-1.7 /* Plus the rest of the PDF body */ }`

Comment: So, `$pdf->getStringBody()` should give you the PDF contents, which you could attach in various ways.

Comment: I would suggest to use the PDF generation method suggested in the plugin's docs: https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/CakePdf#2-create-pdf-for-email-attachment-file-storage-etc

Comment: @ndm Thanks for the suggestion! I followed the tutorial and it indeed works! @Greg Schmidt I am still curious tho, because I included the Cake\Http\Response class but was not able to use the `getStringBody()` function to get the pdf content. The other functionalities as stated on https://api.cakephp.org/4.2/class-Cake.Http.Client.Response.html like `getBody()` did work, is there an explanation for this?